# How to search a folder for a document with variable file type with "*" wildcard?

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I want to search for a document in a folder and return its location.

The document can be either `.xlsx` or `.pdf`; therefore, I want to add `"*"` to the name to find either.

```vb
Sub Test2()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim myFile As File

    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder("Folder Path")
    Set Team3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team 3 & 3a")
    Rng = Team3.Range("B4:B9")
    
    For Each batch In Rng    
        Filename = batch & "*"

        For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders        
            For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files            
                If myFile.Name = Filename Then                
                    MsgBox myFile.Path
                    Exit For                    
                End If                
            Next            
        Next               
    Next
End Sub
```

The wildcard `*` seems to be interpreting it as text. If I replace the `"*"` with `".pdf"` it does find the files, but I need to search for any type of file.

I removed the folder path from the above, but it is searching in the correct folder. The code works, its just the `"*"` that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `=` checks if left and right side are *equal*. You need to use the `like`-operator: `If myFile.Name like Filename Then`

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you! Spent hours trying to solve this and it was something so simple... Learning something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, FunThomas for helping with this. Not sure how this site works, but the following was the answer given by him.

```
Sub Test2()    
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim myFile As File

    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder("Folder Path")
    Set Team3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team 3 & 3a")
    Rng = Team3.Range("B4:B9")

    For Each batch In Rng        
        Filename = batch & "*"
    
        For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders            
            For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files                
                If myFile.Name Like Filename Then                    
                    MsgBox myFile.Path
                    Exit For                        
                End If                    
            Next                
        Next                    
    Next        
End Sub
```